# What is the value of the sum of two greatest integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the value of $[x]+[-x]$, where $x \in \Bbb {R}$?

Definition: $[x] \leq x < [x]+1, x \in \Bbb {R}$

I think I figured out that the value will be either 0 or -1 for all $x \in \Bbb {R}$

For example,

$[2]+[-2]=2+(-2)=0$

$[2.3]+[-2.3]=2+(-3)=-1$

$[\pi]+[-\pi]=3+(-4)=-1$

But besides using examples, how can I prove that this is the case for all $x$?

Comment: Perhaps you could break up $x$ into $x=[x]+(x-[x])$ and see how the arithmetic works out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following, let $\lfloor x\rfloor $ be the largest integer not greater than $x$. ($\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the same as $[x]$ you use.)

For any $x\in\mathbb R$, we have
$$\lfloor x\rfloor \le x\lt \lfloor x\rfloor +1\iff x-1\lt \lfloor x\rfloor \le x\tag1$$
with that the equality is attained if and only if $x$ is an integer.
Also, we have
$$(-x)-1\lt \lfloor -x\rfloor \le -x\tag2$$
with that the equality is attained if and only if $-x$ is an integer.

Hence, calculating $(1)+(2)$ gives us
$$-2\lt \lfloor x\rfloor +\lfloor -x \rfloor \le 0.$$
This leads that
$$\lfloor x\rfloor +\lfloor -x \rfloor=\begin{cases}-1\ \ \ \text{if $x$ is not an integer}\\\ 0\ \ \ \text{if $x$ is an integer}\end{cases}$$

Comment: For $(-x)-1< [x] \leq -x$, how did you get that? Did you do that just by negating the previous $x-1 < [x] \leq x$ or is it the same definition but for $-x$?

Comment: Since $x-1\lt \lfloor x\rfloor \le x$ holds for any $x\in\mathbb R$ (this means that it holds no matter whether $x$ is positive or negative), it holds for $-x$, so we can have $(-x)-1\lt \lfloor -x\rfloor\le -x$.

Answer (score 0):

It is trivial to prove when $x$ is an integer.

When $x$ is not an integer :
$x =  \lfloor x  \rfloor + \theta,  ~0 \lt \theta \lt 1 $

$\implies -x =  -\lfloor x  \rfloor -1 + (1-\theta)$
$\implies \lfloor -x  \rfloor =  -\lfloor x  \rfloor -1 $
$\implies \lfloor -x  \rfloor +\lfloor x  \rfloor = -1 $