# Greatest integer function question

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to show that, if $x \leq y$, then $[x] \leq [y]$, where $x,y \in \Bbb {R}$.

I figured out that $[x] \leq x \leq y$, which would imply that $[x] \leq y$.

I think that I need to now show that $[y] \leq y$.  I don't know how to continue.

Comment: $[x]\leq y$ so necesarily $[y]\geq [x]$ by definition of integer part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $[x]\le x$ holds for any $x\in\mathbb R$, we have
$$[x]\le x\le y\Rightarrow [x]\le y.$$
Since $[x]$ is an integer, we have
$$[x]\le y\Rightarrow [x]\le [y].$$

Comment: I don't understand how you arrived at $[x] \leq y \implies [x] \leq [y]$.  Is it because if $x$ is an integer then $[x] = x$ and so since $x \leq y$ then $[x] \leq [y]$ ?

Comment: @user45417: I think drawing a number line may be helpful. $[x]\le y$ means that $y$ is larger than or equal to **an integer** $[x]$. So, by the definition of $[y]$, we have $[x]\le [y]\le y$. You will see that $[y]$ cannot be smaller than **the integer** $[x]$.

Comment: @user45417: As you commented, you are right in the case that $x$ is an integer. But you need to consider the case that $x$ is not an integer. If $x$ is not an integer, then there exists an integer $m$ such that $m\lt x\lt m+1$, right? So, we have $m=[x]$. So, we have $m\le y$. Here, since $m$ is an integer, note that $[y]$ is larger than or equal to $m$. This implies that $m\le [y]$, which is $[x]\le [y]$.

Comment: So then regardless of whether or not $x$ is an integer, you will still arrive at the same conclusion that $[x] \leq [y]$?

Comment: @user45417: Yes, exactly. That's what I wrote in my answer.

Comment: @user45417: By the way, do you understand my answer of the following your question? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923860/what-is-the-value-of-the-sum-of-two-greatest-integers

Comment: Yes I do.  Thank you very much for your help.  The problem makes sense now.